# Is it meaningful to define a probability distribution (or measure) by projecting the uniform defined on an arbitrary curve?

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions

I have learned that the common ways to define distributions (measures) are by either density probability functions or their integral, the cdf.

I was wondering for fun if an alternate mechanism I am imagining could also be usable or if it has already been studied and is in use.

This would be similar to the density idea, but we assume a $uniform$ on a curve $f(x)$ and project it straight (normalizing as appropriate) on the real line to induce a suitable measure.

This would differ from the density mechanism because the density, intuitively, is a bit like projecting equispaced points with respect to the y axis, while here the equal segments are taken on the curve $f(x)$. (Furthermore, in general, the same projection, I guess, could be obtained with infinitely many different curves.)

I would like to ask if this idea makes any sense and if it is something that has already been explored.

[image]

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: I was thinking, as an example, about a positive unit semicircle with the center at the origin. If we put a uniform distribution on it, the projection on the x-axis should come out as a distribution essentially based on the cosine of x. In general, it would be nice to be able to derive the resulting distribution from any f(x)

Comment: It would work, but it seems to me you're just providing the density function in a very roundabout sort of way.

Comment: Sure, user24142, it would be just another "mechanism" to assign a measure. But in some problems, it could be useful or natural to assign a uniform to a curve and see how its "projection" behaves (probably in some physics problems, it may make sense).  The curve f(x) in this case would not represent a "density." I'm not sure how it could be called at the moment. Maybe the readers will suggest something.

Comment: Something like that, assigning a uniform to some geometrical object and wondering about the distribution of a projection, I think it's also in the Borel-Kolmogorov paradox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you can't assign every curve $y=f(x)$ a uniform distribution, e.g. the real line itself.

Thus we need more conditions. Let's assume $f$ is nonnegative and integrable (with nonzero integral), then  $\tilde f(x)=f(x)\mathbin/\int f(x)\, \mathrm dx$ is a density of a continuous random variable $X$ on $\mathbb R$.
We can assign a uniform distribution on this curve $y=f(x)$ by means of c.d.f $F(x)$ of $X$, since $F(X)\sim\mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$. In this way, the distribution of the projection defined by $(x,f(x))\mapsto x$ is just the distribution of $X$, so we have defined a distribution over the curve $y=f(x)$ whose p.d.f is $\tilde f(x)$ while assigning a uniform distribution on it.

So, it can be seen that defining a distribution on a curve is nothing new because of the fact that the c.d.f follows a uniform distribution.

---

**EDIT**: I think I realize what the "uniform distribution" means in this problem, i.e., the probability of an arc is proportional to the arc length.

Now suppose we have a *smooth* curve $y=f(x)$ where $a\leqslant x\leqslant b$, and the arc length from $a$ to $t$ is $s(t)$. For a continuous random variable $X$ with range $[a,b]$ defined by this curve, the distribution of it is given by $F(t)=s(t)/s(b)$ where $F(t)$ is the c.d.f of $X$.

Conversely, if we have $F(t)$, then $f(t)$ can by solved from
$$
s(t)=\int_a^t \sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}\, \mathrm dx
$$
by taking derivative.

However, I don't think the distribution defined in this way is practical. If you know $F(t)$ then simply taking derivative you will get the density but you have to solve the integral to obtain the curve $y=f(x)$. Integration is more difficult than differntiation.

Comment: I am not sure why I can't assign a uniform to any curve, f(x). Imagine taking innumerable equispaced points on a curve (equispaced on the curve itself)  and projecting them down. Their "spacings" will be different from those (equispaced) on the curve, so they induce a measure on the x axis. The inverse of any CFD is the uniform. But here we are taking an equispaced point on the curve f(x).  It's different from the inverse images (respect to a cdf) being equispaced on the y-axis.

Comment: Take a simple example: you can't assign a uniform distribution on $\mathbb R$, i.e. the curve $y\equiv0$. For the c.d.f part, it seems you didn't get the point...

Comment: In general, there could be "improper" distributions (like the improper uniform prior used often in statistics). Of course, in practice, one can take just a segment of the curve, a portion of a curve f(x) bounded by two points, and "normalize" the resulting measure on the x axis.

Comment: Improper prior is for *inference* in the context of Bayesian statistics. It is not a true probability distribution.

Comment: Yes, ImbalanceDream. What is uniform is the distribution of the curve itself. That is what I was thinking of. Surely, the problem of finding the distribution corresponding to (a segment of) the curve is not very easy.  Probably, one has to impose some extra conditions. Anyway, in math, it's nice to wonder and discover new things just for the fun of it. And, for practical applications, you never know where they can reappear :-)